# Denying access to node form edit

Tags: 7, forms

I need to make some checks on node access form based on user/role attributes that cannot be handled by Drupal core modules, so i think to do them in _form_alter hooks.

Which is the best thing to do when the user has not access to the form edit ? I can do a drupal_goto(...) but i would like to stay in the same form, showing an access denied command. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the standard way to handle this would be to implement [`hook_node_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7), make your checks there, and deny access if any of your conditions aren't met.

This will result in the standard 403 page when a user without the correct permissions tries to access the page, which semantically speaking would probably be the best result.

The code might look something like:

```
function MYMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;

  if ($type == 'my_type' && ($op == 'create' || $op == 'update')) {
    if ($account->something == 'something') { // allow access
      return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
    }
    else {
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
  }

  // Return the default ignore value if your module doesn't need to get involved in this decision
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```